# Wrong Homepage Redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

After the latest Woocommerce update I have the following issue:

If I add some variations to my product and save it, when I click on the product permalink it redirects me to the website's homepage.

I use the Remove Slug from Custom Post Type plugin, my .htacces structure (the plugin code) is:

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^wafp-subscriptions/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product_variation/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop_order_refund/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^vc_grid_item/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^avada_portfolio/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^avada_faq/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^wpcr3_review/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fusion_template/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
```

I spent the whole day trying to solve this issue but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@peter-featherstone the debugging result is:

```
1   RewriteRule ^wafp-subscriptions/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]  This rule was not met.
2   RewriteRule ^product/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L] This rule was not met.
3   RewriteRule ^product_variation/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]   This rule was not met.
4   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
5   RewriteRule ^shop_order_refund/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]   This rule was not met.
6   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
7   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
8   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
9   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
10  RewriteRule ^vc_grid_item/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
11  RewriteRule ^avada_portfolio/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L] This rule was not met.
12  RewriteRule ^avada_faq/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]   This rule was not met.
13  RewriteRule ^wpcr3_review/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
14  RewriteRule ^fusion_template/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L] This rule was not met.
15  RewriteRule ^/(.+)/\$ /\$1 [R=301,L]    This rule was not met.
16  RewriteBase /   Using / as the base for the rewrites.
17  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  This rule was not met.
18  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This condition was met.
19  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d This condition was met.
20  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    The new url is http://www.sitename.be/index.php
```

The tests are stopped because of the L in your RewriteRule options.